# Вращение SVG элемента вокруг центра

Tags: javascript, svg

Проблема заключается в том, что если к элементу уже применена трансформация, в моем случае масштаб, при вращении наблюдается эффект растягивания. Но что конкретно я должен учитывать при создании матрицы вращения не знаю. Цель: вращать любой элемент вокруг центра не зависимо от примененной же к нему трансформации...

**Обновлено**:
Если установить порядок умножения матриц на более верный(как мне кажется)
`translate(x y) X rotate(deg) X translate(-x -y) X CTM`
то проблема с масштабом уходит. Но если элемент до вращения был уже повернут, то
вращать вокруг центра его уже не удается...

```js
const scaled = document.getElementById('scaled');

const sMatrix = scaled.getCTM();

function rotate(el, matrix, radians) {

  const {
    x,
    y,
    width,
    height
  } = el.getBBox();

  const translateMatrix = createSVGMatrix(),
    rotateMatrix = createSVGMatrix();

  const cos = Math.cos(radians),
    sin = Math.sin(radians);
  //scale(0.3, 0.6)
  translateMatrix.e = (x + width / 2) * 0.3;
  translateMatrix.f = (y + height / 2) * 0.6;

  rotateMatrix.a = cos;
  rotateMatrix.b = sin;
  rotateMatrix.c = -sin;
  rotateMatrix.d = cos;

  // Порядок умножения матриц:
  // translate(x y) X rotate(deg) X translate(-x -y) X CTM
  const elMatrix = translateMatrix
    .multiply(rotateMatrix)
    .multiply(translateMatrix.inverse())
    .multiply(matrix);

  el.setAttribute(
    'transform',
    matrixToString(elMatrix)
  );
}

function matrixToString(m) {
  return `matrix(${m.a},${m.b},${m.c},${m.d},${m.e},${m.f})`;
}

function createSVGMatrix() {
  return document
    .createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
    .createSVGMatrix();
}

let r = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  rotate(scaled, sMatrix, r);
  r += 0.1;
}, 50)
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

<g id="scaled" transform="rotate(30) scale(0.3, 0.6)">
<path id="path" d="m99.04713000000004,80.80642999999998 c-31.21513,0,-56.34375,26.03359,-56.34375,58.375 l0,27.71875 c0,32.34141,25.12862,58.40625,56.34375,58.40625 l393,0 c31.21513,0,56.34375,-26.06484,56.34375,-58.40625 l0,-27.71875 c0,-32.34141,-25.12862,-58.375,-56.34375,-58.375 l-393,0 z m36.90625,21.65625,6.78125,0 c13.61323,0,24.5625,8.42733,24.5625,18.90625 l0,63.96875 c0,10.47892,-10.94927,18.90625,-24.5625,18.90625 l-6.78125,0 c-13.61323,0,-24.5625,-8.42733,-24.5625,-18.90625 l0,-63.96875 c0,-10.47892,10.94927,-18.90625,24.5625,-18.90625 z " id="path3.130" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="opacity: 0.95492; fill: rgb(204, 204, 204);" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: я в таких случаях применяю вращение снаружи от скейла а не внутри его, а так простите уж, но вы сами себе приключения ищете

Comment: С приключениями понятно, но что имеете ввиду в `снаружи от скейла`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вращения элемента с трансформацией вокруг центра достаточно следующих действий:

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
const scaled = document.getElementById('scaled');

const sMatrix = scaled.getCTM();

const {
    x,
    y,
    width,
    height
} = scaled.getBBox();

 const pt = root.createSVGPoint();
 pt.x = x + width / 2;
 pt.y = y + height / 2;

// применяем трансформацию элемента к координатам центра
// и находим координаты центра относительно документа
const elCenter = pt.matrixTransform(sMatrix);

const centerPoint = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');

centerPoint.cx.baseVal.value = elCenter.x;
centerPoint.cy.baseVal.value = elCenter.y;
centerPoint.r.baseVal.value = 2;
root.appendChild(centerPoint);


function rotate(el, matrix, radians, center) {

  const translateMatrix = createSVGMatrix(),
    rotateMatrix = createSVGMatrix();

  const cos = Math.cos(radians),
    sin = Math.sin(radians);

  rotateMatrix.a = cos;
  rotateMatrix.b = sin;
  rotateMatrix.c = -sin;
  rotateMatrix.d = cos;
  
  translateMatrix.e = center.x;
  translateMatrix.f = center.y;

// составляем матрицу вращения вокруг центра фигуры
// translate(cx cy) X rotate(deg) X translate(-cx -cy)
 const rMatrix = translateMatrix
    .multiply(rotateMatrix)
    .multiply(translateMatrix.inverse());
    
 // применяем к текущей матрице
 // rotate(deg, cx, cy) X CTM
  const elMatrix = rMatrix.multiply(matrix);

  el.setAttribute(
    'transform',
    matrixToString(elMatrix)
  );
}

function matrixToString(m) {
  return `matrix(${m.a},${m.b},${m.c},${m.d},${m.e},${m.f})`;
}

function createSVGMatrix() {
  return document
    .createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
    .createSVGMatrix();
}

let r = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  rotate(scaled, sMatrix, r, elCenter);
  r += 0.1;
}, 50)
```

```html
<svg id="root" width="100%" height="100%">

<g id="scaled" transform="skewX(10) translate(10, 10) rotate(10) scale(0.4, 0.3)">
<path id="path" d="m99.04713000000004,80.80642999999998 c-31.21513,0,-56.34375,26.03359,-56.34375,58.375 l0,27.71875 c0,32.34141,25.12862,58.40625,56.34375,58.40625 l393,0 c31.21513,0,56.34375,-26.06484,56.34375,-58.40625 l0,-27.71875 c0,-32.34141,-25.12862,-58.375,-56.34375,-58.375 l-393,0 z m36.90625,21.65625,6.78125,0 c13.61323,0,24.5625,8.42733,24.5625,18.90625 l0,63.96875 c0,10.47892,-10.94927,18.90625,-24.5625,18.90625 l-6.78125,0 c-13.61323,0,-24.5625,-8.42733,-24.5625,-18.90625 l0,-63.96875 c0,-10.47892,10.94927,-18.90625,24.5625,-18.90625 z " id="path3.130" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="opacity: 0.95492; fill: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так (при помощи дополнительной группы сверху в иерархии элементов) вращать svg элемент намного проще:

Для этого необходимо лишь определить точку, вокруг которой нужно вращать.

Сделать это можно при помощи [`.getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

```js
let gr1 = document.querySelector('#rotateGroup1');
let gr2 = document.querySelector('#rotateGroup2');
let gr3 = document.querySelector('#rotateGroup3');
  
requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(dt){
  rotate(gr1, dt/10);
  rotate(gr2, -dt/5);
  rotate(gr3, dt/5);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
  
function rotate(el, value) {
  let bb = el.getBBox();
  let cx = bb.x + bb.width/2;
  let cy = bb.y + bb.height/2;
  el.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${value} ${cx},${cy})`)
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 100" height="100%">
  <g id="rotateGroup1">
    <g transform='scale(1.3, 1.6)'>
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="rotateGroup2">
    <g transform='scale(1.7, 1.2)'>
      <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="10"></circle>
    </g>
  </g>
    <g id="rotateGroup3">
    <g transform='translate(100,0) scale(0.3)'>
      <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за вариант решения, но им воспользоваться не могу, так как задача стоит иначе. Решение нашёл, чуть позже добавлю в вопрос.